# Tidymodels How to extract tuned parameter with workflow map and collect_metrics?

Tags: r, tidymodels

Hello I noticed that `collect_metrics` function does not return the parameter of interest in this case Cost Complexity. I am not sure why this is the case. I created a small example with the iris dataset to show this.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(baguette)

set.seed(222)


# Put 3/4 of the data into the training set 
data_split <- initial_split(iris, prop = 3/4)

# Create data frames for the two sets:
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)



# Create Recipes ----

Sepal_length_rec <- recipe(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = train_data)

Petal.Length_rec <- recipe(Petal.Length ~ ., data = train_data)


## Create Model -----

rpart_mod <- bag_tree() |> 
  set_engine("rpart") |> 
  set_mode("regression") |> 
  set_args(times = 10,
           cost_complexity = tune("cost_complexity"))

grid = tibble(cost_complexity = as.numeric(seq(from = 0, to = .01, by = .01)))

## Create workflow ----

model_set <- 
  workflow_set(
    preproc = list(Sepal = Sepal_length_rec, 
                   Petal = Petal.Length_rec),
    models = list(rpart_model = rpart_mod),
    cross = TRUE)

# Tuning -----
train_resamples <- vfold_cv(train_data, v = 2)

model_set <- model_set |> 
  workflow_map("tune_grid", resamples = train_resamples, grid = grid, verbose = TRUE)
#> i 1 of 2 tuning:     Sepal_rpart_model
#> ✔ 1 of 2 tuning:     Sepal_rpart_model (1.4s)
#> i 2 of 2 tuning:     Petal_rpart_model
#> ✔ 2 of 2 tuning:     Petal_rpart_model (1.1s)
```

Here the cost complexity column is not included.

```
collect_metrics(model_set) #Cost complexity not included
#> # A tibble: 8 × 9
#>   wflow_id          .config preproc model .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err
#>   <chr>             <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 Sepal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rmse    standard   0.358     2 4.23e-2
#> 2 Sepal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rsq     standard   0.798     2 1.91e-2
#> 3 Sepal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rmse    standard   0.356     2 2.57e-2
#> 4 Sepal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rsq     standard   0.803     2 5.35e-4
#> 5 Petal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rmse    standard   0.301     2 6.40e-2
#> 6 Petal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rsq     standard   0.968     2 1.42e-2
#> 7 Petal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rmse    standard   0.340     2 6.45e-2
#> 8 Petal_rpart_model Prepro… recipe  bag_… rsq     standard   0.961     2 1.84e-2
```

Though you can see inside the results that the cost complexity data is present

```
model_set$result[[1]]$.metrics
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   cost_complexity .metric .estimator .estimate .config             
#>             <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1            0    rmse    standard       0.315 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 2            0    rsq     standard       0.817 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 3            0.01 rmse    standard       0.330 Preprocessor1_Model2
#> 4            0.01 rsq     standard       0.803 Preprocessor1_Model2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   cost_complexity .metric .estimator .estimate .config             
#>             <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1            0    rmse    standard       0.400 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 2            0    rsq     standard       0.779 Preprocessor1_Model1
#> 3            0.01 rmse    standard       0.382 Preprocessor1_Model2
#> 4            0.01 rsq     standard       0.804 Preprocessor1_Model2
```

Does anyone know a way for me to extract out the tuned parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't return the parameter values because we can't guarantee that the parameter set will be the same across workflows.

You can use `extract_workflow_set_result()` to get the ones that you want and manipulate them:

```r
> model_set %>% 
+     # The next line gets you the tune_results object
+     extract_workflow_set_result("Sepal_rpart_model") %>% 
+     # do whatever you would normally do. 
+     select_best(metric = "rmse")
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  cost_complexity .config             
            <dbl> <chr>               
1            0.01 Preprocessor1_Model2
```

Comment: If I wanted to compare across multiple workflow id then I could make a vector of workflow and use the extract workflow set function with map?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it manually is an option and not relying on the `collect_metrics` functions

```
model_results <-  model_set$result

names(model_results) <- model_set$wflow_id

model_results <- map_dfr(model_results, ~.x, .id = "model")

model_metrics <- model_results |> 
  select(model, id, .metrics) |> 
  unnest(.metrics)
```

The model_metrics object is the raw metrics that you can summarize however you like.

For example with `group_by`

```
model_metrics |> 
  group_by(model, cost_complexity, .metric) |> 
  summarize(.estimate = mean(.estimate),
            n = n())
```

Comment: There is a simpler method using an existing API (see the other answer).